# nginx: location for allowed ips; PHP Include?

Tags: php, nginx

my PHP include:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.socket;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I try to allow the access to files in a directory by location:

```
   location ~ /internal {
           allow IP;
           deny all;
   }
```

It works, but php files in this directory can be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Keep in mind that: Nginx always chooses only one location block to match a request. The search order is:

1. `=`
2. `^~`
3. `None`
4. `~`
5. `~*`
6. `@`

so, a request `/internal/foo.php` is matched by the prefix location `/internal` first, then the search terminated and regular expression were not checked. It is why you get a download dialog when requesting PHP files.

To avoid duplicate, put the common directive into a separate file and use the [`include`](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include) directive, something like this:

**`/etc/nginx/php.conf`**

```
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.socket;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

**`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`**

```
location /internal {
    allow IP;
    deny all;

    location ~ ^/internal(.*\.php)$ {
        include php.conf;
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include php.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a php location for the inside of the /internal location, like:

```
location ~ /internal/\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.socket;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```